# How to create EF Core ID one-step?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm learning EF Core and making ID on the below POCO Road's property rid

```
public class Road
{
    public int rid { get; set; }
    public string rname { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
},
```

Currently my solution is two-step:

1: adding PK

2: using ValueGeneratedOnAdd() method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Road>()
       .HasKey(x => x.rid);

modelBuilder.Entity<Road>()
       .Property(x =>x.rid)
       .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

I want a one-step solution, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an extension method:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions 
{
    public static EntityTypeBuilder<T> HasKeyWithValueGeneratedOnAdd<T>(
        this EntityTypeBuilder<T> b,
        Expression<Func<T, object>> expression) 
    where T : class
    {
      b.HasKey(expression);
      b.Property(expression).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
      return b;
    }
}
```

Then use it as a one-liner:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Road>().HasKeyWithValueGeneratedOnAdd(x => x.rid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class Road
        {
            [Key]
            public int rid { get; set; }

            public string rname { get; set; }
            public string zip { get; set; }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want annotation solution.